# Can a static reference be used as a "flag" with an atomic linked list?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, interlocked

When using atomics in c++, I can pack other variables in the unused address bits of pointers.  I can the atomically change flags, counters, etc along with a pointer.  In c#, this is not so easy.  I think I can use static references that mean special things, but I am slightly worried about gc moving references when it compacts the heap.  For instance, in this sample code, can atomically mark a linked list as closed to adding by using a static reference, s_cantAddWork.  My question is, do I have to worry about gc moving s_cantAddWork?  Do I need to use Fixed?  So far, after running code like this for a long time, it seems safe.  I'd like to hear it from an expert though.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Testola {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // pile = null
            var w = new CWork();
            if (!AtomicAddWork(w))
                Console.WriteLine("Cant add work!"); // not hit
            // pile = 1
            w = new CWork();
            if (!AtomicAddWork(w))
                Console.WriteLine("Cant add work!"); // not hit
            // pile = 2,1
            w = AtomicGetWork();
            // pile = 1
            w = new CWork();
            if (!AtomicAddWork(w))
                Console.WriteLine("Cant add work!"); // not hit
            // pile = 3,1

            // remove everything from pile and disable adding.

            w = AtomicGetAllWorkAndLockOutOtherThreadsFromAddingMoreWork();
            // pile = s_cantAddWork
            w = new CWork();
            if (!AtomicAddWork(w))
                Console.WriteLine("Cant add work!");  // HITS THIS!
        }

        public class CWork {
            static int s_cItems = 0;
            public static CWork s_cantAddWork = new CWork();
            public CWork next;
            public string data = (s_cItems++).ToString();
        }
        static volatile CWork m_workPile;
        static bool AtomicAddWork(CWork work) {
            while (true) {
                var Old = m_workPile;
                // WHAT HAPPENS HERE IF GC MOVES s_cantAddWork? <<------------------
                // I assume Old is moved too, and all threads are stopped, so my atomic stuff will still work.
                if (Old == CWork.s_cantAddWork)
                    return false;
                work.next = Old;
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_workPile, work, Old) == Old)
                    return true; // success
                work.next = null;
            }
        }
        static CWork AtomicGetWork() {
            while (true) {
                var Old = m_workPile;
                if (Old == null)
                    return null;
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_workPile, Old.next, Old) == Old)
                    return Old; // success
            }
        }
        static CWork AtomicGetAllWorkAndLockOutOtherThreadsFromAddingMoreWork() {
            while (true) {
                var Old = m_workPile;
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_workPile, CWork.s_cantAddWork, Old) == Old)
                    return Old; // success
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to know or care if the GC moves something unless you are working with unsafe code. There is no unsafe code in your example.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe.

References aren't the same as address pointers. When c# moves memory around it will be transparent your code unless you are using unsafe operations like the address of operator.

To obtain the address of a unary expression, which evaluates to a fixed variable, use the address-of operator:[[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbcf4ta.aspx)]

```
 int* p = &number;
```

If you were using addresses, then you would need to mark your code as unsafe using the unsage keyword. At that point you would likely want to pin the address using the fixed statemnt.

Also, take a look at this question for more details:

[How does the GC update references after compaction occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669173/how-does-the-gc-update-references-after-compaction-occurs)