# How does the .net garbage collector fixes the references?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I'm a very experienced .Net developer, and have very deep knowledge of "all" of the in-and-outs of C# and .Net. But there's one question that puzzles me for a very long time about the garbage collector.

Of course that I know all the "regular stuff" about how the .Net garbage collector works. I know about the generations, and how it determines which objects it can free. I know that after freeing the unused objects it compacts the remaining objects to be adjacent. But what I don't understand is how does it update the references to the objects that it moves, in an efficient manner?

I mean, it can traverse the entire object graph again to find the references that need to be fixed, and fix them. But it needs to do this for every object that it moves, and during this process none of these objects can be accessed safely.

At first I thought that references are not really pointers, but only indexes to to an array of pointers to the real objects. This way, moving an object only involves updating the only pointer in the table instead of all of the references. However, having debugging some disassembly I don't see that this is what happens. I also remember that I once realized a serious flaw to this hypothetical solution, but I can't recall what it was...

Does anyone (Jon Skeet? :-)) can shed some light on this question?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669173/how-does-the-gc-update-references-after-compaction-occurs ? Won't mark it as duplicate since there is no accepted answer.